# FTP plugin into wp-content/plugins folder but does not appear installed in dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, ftp

My plugin does not appear as a choice in my WordPress dashboard plugin section

I downloaded the Duplicator plugin zip file to my computer. Extracted the zip folder. I FTPed the extracted Duplicator plugin folder into the wp-content/plugins folder of my live site. According to WPbeginner.com, that's all that is necessary to install the plugin and I should see it as a choice in the plugin section of my website's dashboard. However, it does not appear. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that when you extract the plugin from the zip, that it doesn't add an extra sub-directory. The folder that you upload in `wp-content/plugins` should have the files at its root.